# Расшифровать хэш, или подобрать фразу с таким же хэшем

Tags: php, пароль, хеширование, шифрование

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые гики и простые обыватели этого форума. Мне нужна ваша помощь!

Есть у меня хэш некой фразы (длина не известна), зашифрованный методом `crypt()`. Есть соль, с помощью которой шифровалась. Требуется сделать расшифровку, или подобрать фразу таким образом, чтоб с использованием этой соли хэши совпали.

Что я уже сделал: написал php-скрипт, который делает последовательный перебор символов `[a-zA-Z0-9]` от одного символа в фразе до десяти. Запустил скрипт в терминале линукса. В общей сложности за 15 часов работы продвинулся только до `gaaa`. Я так буду бесконечно подбирать.

Есть ли какие-то более быстрые способы, не обязательно на PHP. Работаю на линуксе (CentOS 7).

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Лучшие ответы награждаются лайками, а полезные принятыми! :)

С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: > Лучшие ответы награждаются лайками, а полезные принятыми! :)

Всю жизнь мечтал.

Comment: @Etki что, так редко благодарные люди попадаются? Или вам эти лайки настолько безразличны? :)

Comment: @intro94, второе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все 6 алгоритмов шифрования, на которых основана функция `crypt()` (а это DES, Extended DES, MD5, Blowfish, SHA256 и SHA512) являются необратимыми, поэтому получить из зашифрованной строки исходную любым способом, отличным от перебора, невозможно. В MD5 и DES используются относительно короткие ключи, поэтому перебор может дать результат за разумное время. Остальные алгоритмы ломать перебором при текущих вычислительных мощностях нецелесообразно. Если у вас нет знакомых в АНБ, которые могут подсказать, какие именно "закладки" заложены в перечисленные алгоритмы, то лучшим советом будет забить. Если же вы всё ещё упорно желаете сломать шифр перебором, то стоит задуматься о запуске распределённого перебора на нескольких машинах (ботнет?), причём не в интерпретаторе PHP, а на видеокарте с помошью CUDA и подобных технологий.

Comment: @fori1ton, о ботнете думал, но это будет немного незаконно, не думаете ли? :D

Насчёт графического ускорения: знать бы, как устроить его программно. Желательно на обоих системах: и на линуксе, и на windows-е как это сделать можно? Я вообще на хабре статью недавно нашёл, что какие-то спецы за счёт ssd (?) подбирали сложные пассы за считанные секунды (5).

[статья на хабре](http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/107243/)

Попробую скачать ту программку.

А как дело обстоит с графическим ускорением?  Как им воспользоваться? На каких языках можно реализовать подбор пароля за счёт графического ускорения?

Comment: @intro94, кластер серверов, занимающийся тем же, чем вы занимаетесь сейчас, не будет более незаконным.

Comment: @intro94, если внимательно прочитать приведённую вами статью, то можно увидеть словосочетание "_радужные таблицы_". По сути радужные таблицы - это просто база данных, которая хранит пароли и их просчитанные хэши. В описанном эксперименте сначала сгенерировали __все__ 14-значные пароли и просчитали их хэши, затем записали их на SSD и написали программу, которая ищет хэщи в этой базе. SSD там нужны лишь для ускорения поиска по баз готовых хэшей, генерация этих хэщей как была долгой, так и остаётся.

Comment: @intro94, расчёты на GPU обыно осуществляются при помощи специализированных языков или библиотек вроде CUDA или OpenCL. Также возможен вариант вычислений посредством шейдеров, но это удовольствия для редкостных эстетов.

Comment: @intro94, как я понял, у вас есть всё, чтоб сгенерировать новый пароль для админа. Так что вам мешает это сделать и вручную переписать в базе?

Comment: @intro94, ну зайдете Вы админом на сайт, нагадите. Допустим, они потеряют какие-то деньги, *а дальше-то что*?

Получается как в присказке: "пусть лучше у соседа корова сдохнет, чем у меня две появятся".